# How do I get XSLT to stop using scientific notation when outputting the results of numeric operations?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have a bit of XSLT which is performing some magic on integer database identifiers.  The relevant code snippit is

```
      <xsl:variable name="releaseId" select="@ID + $contentOffsetId"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="OLD_ID"> <xsl:value-of select="@ID" /> </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="RELEASE_ID"> <xsl:value-of select="$releaseId" />
```

Unfortunately the output from this looks like this:

```
<ALBUM.RELEASE_LOCALE LOCALE_CODE="en_US" OLD_ID="6597512" RELEASE_ID="6.597513E6">
```

This result is useless to me since I won't be able to use the scientific notation entry as input to my DB import utility.  I've tried a number of functions on the variable declaration, such as `string(@ID + $contentOffsetId)` but nothing seems to achieve the desired results.

The XSL is being executed using Saxon 8.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [format-number](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp) (for detailed reference: [here](http://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-xpath-function-reference/alphabetical-xslt-and-xpath-reference/format-number/))

Comment: Why the hell isn't that function listed on this page:  http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: @Jherico - because it is an ***XSLT*** function, not an ***XPATH*** function.

Comment: Actually, as this [page][1] points out, xpath, xslt and xquery share the same function set, which is why I felt comfortable relying on that page.  However, the same page also points out that there are some built in XSLT functions that are outside the set.  

   [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `@ID` and `$contentOffsetId` are both integers masquerading as doubles, and the best strategy would be to use integer arithmetic to add them rather than floating-point arithmetic. The conversion to string will then use the rules for integers rather than the rules for doubles, which will avoid the use of scientific notation.

You haven't shown us where `$contentOffsetId` comes from, but if my guess is correct, declare it as an integer using `as="xs:integer"` on the variable declaration.

As for `@ID`, my guess is that your stylesheet isn't schema aware and therefore `@ID` is untyped atomic; you can convert it to integer using `xs:integer(@ID)`. The default when untyped atomic values are used in arithmetic expressions is to convert to `xs:double`, but this is largely a legacy from XSLT 1.0 and is often inappropriate.

Incidentally in XSLT 2.0 you can replace

```
<xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="Y"/></xsl:attribute>
```

by

```
<xsl:attribute name="x" select="Y"/>
```